# How to sort rows in pandas with a non-standard order

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, say:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ([['a', 3, 3], ['b', 2, 5], ['c', 4, 9], ['d', 1, 43]], columns = ['col 1' , 'col2', 'col 3'])
```

or:

```
  col 1  col2  col 3
0     a     3      3
1     b     2      5
2     c     4      9
3     d     1     43
```

If I want to sort by col2, I can use df.sort, and that will sort ascending and descending.

However, if I want to sort the rows so that col2 is: [4, 2, 1, 3], how would I do that?

Comment: Is [4, 2, 1, 3] a function of a column in the DataFrame or do you have it as a list from another process?

Comment: It's a list from some other process. It's arbitrary.

Comment: In the actual example, it's a bunch strings that come from a completely separate DF. ALso, there may duplicates in Col 2, but I don't think that should matter

Comment: That was going to be my next question. You can temporarily set it as an index (`df.set_index('col2').loc[lst].reset_index()`) but that wouldn't work in case of duplicates. How are you going to differentiate duplicates? Say, if col2 is [3, 2, 1, 3] and the list is [2, 3, 1, 3] is there a way to know which 3 corresponds to which 3 in the original column?

Comment: @BrianPostow, is it possible that you will have duplicates in the desired orderer list: `[4, 2, 1, 3]` and if yes is it possible to have splits like this: `[4,2,1,3,4]`?

Comment: yes, any input order is possible.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
sortMap = {4:1, 2:2, 1:3,3:4 }
df["new"] = df2['col2'].map(sortMap)
df.sort_values('new', inplace=True)
df

   col1  col2  col3  new
2    c     4     9    1
1    b     2     5    2
3    d     1    43    3
0    a     3     3    4
```

alt method to create dict:

```
ll      = [4, 2, 1, 3] 
sortMap = dict(zip(ll,range(len(ll))))
```

Answer (score 4):

One way is to convert that column to a `Categorical` type, which can have an arbitrary ordering.

```
In [51]: df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('category', categories=[4, 1, 2, 3], ordered=True)

In [52]: df.sort_values('col2')
Out[52]: 
  col 1 col2  col 3
2     c    4      9
3     d    1     43
1     b    2      5
0     a    3      3
```

Comment: it's a smart solution!

Comment: I think this would only work if duplicates in the list are next to each other.

Comment: @ayhan, when i tested it this way: `df = pd.concat([df] * 5, ignore_index=True).sample(frac=1).reset_index(); df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('category', categories=[4, 1, 2, 3], ordered=True); df.sort_values('col2')` - it worked properly...

Comment: Assume `col2` is [4, 2, 4, 1]. You cannot pass this as `categories`, you need to remove duplicates. And if you pass [4, 2, 1] it will sort like [4, 4, 2, 1].

Comment: Right, but isn't that the desired ordering?

Comment: If in the desired order duplicates are grouped together, yes. But assume the desired order is [4, 1, 2, 4], would this work?

Comment: Fair enough, although at that point the desired ordering is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution:

```
In [409]: lst = [4, 2, 1, 3]

In [410]: srt = pd.Series(np.arange(len(lst)), index=lst)

In [411]: srt
Out[411]:
4    0
2    1
1    2
3    3
dtype: int32

In [412]: df.assign(x=df.col2.map(srt))
Out[412]:
  col 1  col2  col 3  x
0     a     3      3  3
1     b     2      5  1
2     c     4      9  0
3     d     1     43  2

In [413]: df.assign(x=df.col2.map(srt)).sort_values('x')
Out[413]:
  col 1  col2  col 3  x
2     c     4      9  0
1     b     2      5  1
3     d     1     43  2
0     a     3      3  3

In [414]: df.assign(x=df.col2.map(srt)).sort_values('x').drop('x',1)
Out[414]:
  col 1  col2  col 3
2     c     4      9
1     b     2      5
3     d     1     43
0     a     3      3
```

NOTE: i do like [@chrisb's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38857529/5741205) more - it's much more elegant and probably will work faster